# High EMI PCB track under transistor or diode package

Tags: pcb, design, switch-mode-power-supply, layout, full-bridge

Can a high EMI PCB track under a transistor or diode package (in this case TO247AC) be a problem?

[image: full-bridge PCB layout]

To get a better understanding:

[image: full-bridge PCB render image]

Is there any advantage on putting these tracks on the other side (like the image above)?

[image: full-bridge PCB render image]

**If these two options might present problems, what would be a good idea?** making a "bus" vertical to the board? Using wires (really great dimensioned to reduce stray inductance)?

The same for the diodes:

[image: rectifier PCB layout]

Note: The transistor case is common to collector, so in **two of the switches** the PCB track under it is common to the case and I think this is not a big problem. **But the other two don't**.

**Some information about the voltage and current:**

- **DC Link voltage:** ~340V.
- **PEAK current at the IGBT:** 75A (at full load on the peak of the switching waveform).
- **Rectified secondary voltage:** maximum of 25V/200A at full-load, and 60V at "no-load".
- **Switching frequency:** ~20Khz maybe a bit more if the switching becomes so audible.

---

*The edges will be rounded, it's just not the final design yet.*

*The BUS tracks although not easy to see is one on each side, so to reduce inductance and add capacitance, also giving a nice design and space use, based on http://xellers.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/general-purpose-h-bridge-inverter/*. Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "high EMI"? These traces are pretty large and as such, they are going to have large capacitance values. If a fast switching signal is to go through them, this capacitance might effect the signal. As you mentioned, these transistors have a huge metal plate on their back which is the collector and it seems the large traces are also the collector so I don't think they will be affected. I'm only concerned about general signal integrity. It might be worth it spinning a small prototype board and testing it.

Comment: @EvangelosEm I will define as high dv/dt and di/dt. The traces as I know *should be large (width) and shorter in length to lower the inductance, this is by far a concern than the capacitance*. The traces as explained are not common to all transistors collectors. This traces are of lower width than the working circuit you can access at the link in the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: I have no experience with this type of application and I might be ignorant of some subtlety of the project so take this with a grain of salt. After taking a look at the application, it seems you won't really mind if the board becomes an unintentional transmitter. Signal integrity doesn't seem to matter either. I would only have the traces on opposite sides on the board just for the larger clearance and creepage since you will be using high voltage/current. This is also suggested by the article you linked, if you look closely at the pictures.

Comment: @EvangelosEm Thanks. The project I linked is just about the full-bridge and the board. My project does not involve a step-up transformer, but a step-down. The secondary potential will be at full-load 25V or a bit more with 200A (peak of 250A). No load of 60V maximum. This is for a welding machine, so its enclosed and EMI can be reduced to the outside.

Comment: EMI means Electromagnetic Interference. A track will never be a "HIGH EMI track" It doesn´t make sense at all. A track features can be: High switching track, high power track, high impedance... but never high EMI. Please, rewrite your question.

Comment: If we talk about switching signal (switching node) we have to talk about the loop this signal creates, i.e. the signal path and his return path. Coudl you provide more information in your question?

Comment: @JesúsCastañé Thanks, I know what is EMI, for me a track (well the circuit it forms, or the current loop) that has a high dv/dt and high di/dt will generate higher EMI. Sorry if this is wrong, fell free to correct the title. I explained some of the signal information, like voltage, peak current and switching frequency. Being it a full-bridge SMPS, the nodes in question are connected to the primary of an isolated transformer (possibly thought a decoupling capacitor), anyway I really think the information you want are at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two transients to consider:

1. High dV/dt: these occur on the switching node (emitter of high-side IGBT and collector of low-side IGBT), each time you switch either IGBT. A high dV/dt can couple to neighboring traces capacitively. If the neighboring trace terminates to a high impedance node (eg. the input to a comparator for current sensing), the capacitive current spike would cause a voltage spike. For a comparator, that could mean a spurious trigger.

A solution is to minimize the overlap area of high dV/dt nodes with sensitive nodes.

In your PCB layout (top image), the upper and lower blue traces are the nodes that see high dV/dt. Since these overlap with nothing, I don't see any issue. It doesn't matter whether they are on the top or bottom planes.

1. High dI/dt: this happens when the current switches from the high side to low side or vice versa. High dI/dt can result in a couple of issues:
   a. Result in a voltage drop across parasitic inductance that is in the path of the current
   b. Induce a voltage in neighboring traces.

A solution to (b) is to minimize the area of all high current loops, and hence minimize the side-by-side trace lengths of high dI/dt nodes and sensitive ones.

Given your configuration where the TO-247AC package (plastic/mold compound) contacts the solder mask, the closest electrically conductive nodes to your PCB traces are the bondwires inside the package that loop over from the leadframe to the die. These wires are tiny, and depending on the metal type no more than 10's of mils in diameter,  coming close to the surface of the package [1]. So the overlap area is negligible.

[1] Nice photo of the pre-molded TO-247: http://www.power-eetimes.com/imf/c/eyJtYXNrIjoiNDMyeDI4OCJ9/images/01-edit-photo-uploads/2014/2014-06-june/onsar2662_fig-1.jpg

Comment: Thanks. As other responses I already know that, the DC BUS is layered to reduce stray inductance and add capacitance. The parasitic inductance on the upper and lower traces are minimized by higher track width and lower length (if considering only these an approximation calculation of the stray inductance of each will be near 30nH). As will see the transformer is not on the PCB so there wires to the transformer that will present stray inductance too (twisting the wires will cancel much of the inductance and add capacitance). The high voltage spike is more a concern to the switching devices than

Comment: to other components (but thanks for nothing that on other components its true). This high voltage spike is reduced by good snubber.

Comment: The question is about the transistor and diodes packages being on top of the tracks, and so can pose any parasitic effect. If you have any information on this, possibly authoritative, I will glad reward the bounty to you.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Looks like 20vero isn't responding.  There shouldn't be any noticeable, if any at all, parasitic effects.  The internals of the transistors and diodes will not effect anything in those tracks since neither generate a primary magnetic field.  If they were inductors, that'd be a different story.  If you are so worried any problems though, It would be beneficial to place the tracks on the other side to get a good amount of space between the components internals and the tracks.  That would mitigate any parasitic effect on the tracks by the components.

Comment: I'm not on SE full-time :). Agree with @Funkyguy. I can add that I work on the packaging of more complex modules with multiple silicon die. Given your configuration (plastic/mold compound) "touching" the solder mask, the closest electrically conductive nodes to your PCB traces are the bondwires inside the TO-220 package that loop over coming close to the surface of the TO-220. These are tiny (diameter in single digit mils) so the overlap area is negligible.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Make sure you give the bounty to 20vero

Comment: @2over0 I think Funkyguy said you are not responding because of the bounty time that has ended, so that I can give it to you. Anyway If you can please edit your question to your really helpful comment so I can mark it the answer that will give you good reputation points. Just a correction, they are TO-247AC.

Comment: @2over0 Just one more doubt, the case is plastic/mold compound but have the metal tab that is common to the collector, as is in the photo you linked. This is not a problem as the tracks are not common to the collector for two of the IGBTs?

Comment: In the 3D model images, it appears the plastic side is what will make contact (albeit a poor thermal one) with the PCB. The metal tab side will, I assume, be fastened to a heat sink via an electrically-isolating thermal interface material. No issue.

Comment: @2over0 yes the metal tab is fastened to the heat sink. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You question regards basic signal integrity principles.

You will want to avoid sending tracks through vias as much as possible since as frequency increases, vias will cause reflects on the traces which will introduce an new noise source.  The only one I would say is okay to send through vias is the connections to the GND plane and connections going to a POWER plane.  Apart from that, keep signals away from vias.

With that said, routing thick traces in parallel will introduce a parasitic capacitance between the two, although if you are working with the 20khz frequency, I don't see too much of a problem with the parasitics.

Comment: Did you read the question? *Its about the high di/dt and dv/dt tracks under the IGBT package*. The two tracks of the DC-BUS are designed TO HAVE a capacitance and reduce stray inductance. The legs top-bottom tracks seems a bit distance to make a significant capacitive coupling, there are papers that say to have them even close so that the opposing currents cancels the effect. Also I didn't use vias to router the power signals, the package is thought hole so the pads will make a via anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, well it would help if you clarified that in the question a bit better and then left a friendly comment asking me to revise my answer to better fit what you are asking for

Comment: Sorry, the comment is friendly. I just repeated some of the things that are already in the question, that's why it sounds a bit non-friendly.